# How to search/filter node content inside of xml file with SimpleXMLElement - php

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I need to filter/search all links (png,jpg,mp3) from an XXML file but I got stuck there. I did for example to get all mp3 but I did it knowing that was there, but for example if I put other file where the path is different, then it won't detect it.

```
    foreach($xml->BODY->GENERAL->SOUNDS->SOUND as $a){
    echo '<a href="'.$a->PATH.'">'.$a->PATH.'</a><br>';
    }
```

[Example XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMktW.png)

Comment: You want to check the extension of `$a->PATH`?

Comment: yes and do a foreach of all xml file to check the extension, then show up this links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the extension of each file and compare it to an array of "accepted extensions". Then use, `continue` to skip to write link:

```
$accepted_exts = ['png','jpg','mp3'];
foreach($xml->BODY->GENERAL->SOUNDS->SOUND as $a) {
    $path = $a->PATH;
    $ext = strtolower(substr($path, strrpos($path, '.') + 1));
    if (!in_array($ext, $accepted_exts)) continue ; // continue to next iteration
    echo '<a href="'.$path.'">'.$path.'</a><br>'; // write the link
}
```

---

To get other links:

```
$accepted_exts = ['png','jpg','mp3'];
$links = [] ;
foreach($xml->HEAD as $items) {
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $path = (string)$item;
        if (!in_array(get_ext($path), $accepted_exts)) continue ; // continue to next iteration
        $links[] = $path ;
    }
}
foreach($xml->BODY->GENERAL->SOUNDS->SOUND as $a) {
    $path = $a->PATH;
    if (!in_array(get_ext($path), $accepted_exts)) continue ; // continue to next iteration
    $links[] = $path ;
}
foreach ($links as $path) {
    echo '<a href="'.$path.'">'.$path.'</a><br>'; // write the link
}
function get_ext($path) {
    return strtolower(substr($path, strrpos($path, '.') + 1));
}
```

Will outputs:

```
<a href="http://player.glifing.com/img/Player/blue.png">http://player.glifing.com/img/Player/blue.png</a><br>
<a href="http://player.glifing.com/img/Player/blue_intro.png">http://player.glifing.com/img/Player/blue_intro.png</a><br>
<a href="http://player.glifing.com/upload/fondoinstrucciones2.jpg">http://player.glifing.com/upload/fondoinstrucciones2.jpg</a><br>
<a href="http://player.glifing.com/upload/stopbet2.png">http://player.glifing.com/upload/stopbet2.png</a><br>
<a href="http://player.glifing.com/upload/goglif2.png">http://player.glifing.com/upload/goglif2.png</a><br>
<a href="http://player.glifing.com/img/Player/Glif 3 OK.png">http://player.glifing.com/img/Player/Glif 3 OK.png</a><br>
<a href="http://player.glifing.com/img/Player/BetPensant.png">http://player.glifing.com/img/Player/BetPensant.png</a><br>
<a href="http://player.glifing.com/audio/Player/si.mp3">http://player.glifing.com/audio/Player/si.mp3</a><br>
<a href="http://player.glifing.com/audio/Player/no.mp3">http://player.glifing.com/audio/Player/no.mp3</a><br>
```

Comment: Thanks! One thing, you know how to iterate the entire xml to check it all? In "Example XML" is an image of it.

Comment: @ToniTJK Could you add to your answer an example of the XML please? Thank you.

Comment: yeees, it has helped me a lot, thanks again! (PD: srry for repeat, just in case, I couldn't edit)

Comment: You're welcome. Take also a look to the interesting answer of @NigelRen. (Don't forget to delete your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49382378/9193372), and your previous comment ;) Thanks!)

Answer (score 0):

To save having to know which individual tags may contain a URL, you can use XPath to search for any text content that starts with "http://" or "https://".  Then process each part to check the extension.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("data.xml");
$extensions = ['png', 'jpg', 'mp3'];
$links = $xml->xpath('//text()[starts-with(normalize-space(), "http://")
    or starts-with(normalize-space(), "https://")]');
foreach ( $links as $link ) {
    $link = trim(trim($link),"_");
    $path = parse_url($link, PHP_URL_PATH);
    $extension = strtolower(pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    if ( in_array($extension, $extensions)) {
        // Do something
        echo $link.PHP_EOL;
    }
    else   {
        echo "Rejected:".$link.PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

I found that using `trim()` helped clean up URL's which had blank lines after them (or at least some extra whitespace).  And convert them all to lower to make checking easier.

You may not need the rejected bit, but I put it in to test my code.

You would have to repeat the above